# How to correctly create a bounded generic class that extends a generic interface in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm,trying to implement a generic messaging system. Depending on the destination the class must implements different interfaces to be correctly deserialized by the server.

For this i have those interfaces:

```
public interface IBasicInput
public interface IBasicOutput
public interface IMessage <I,O>
```

And class implementations:

```
public class BasicInput1 implements IBasicInput
public class BasicOutput1 implements IBasicOutput
public class Type1Message<I extends IBasicInput,O extends IBasicOutput> implements IMessage<I, O> {

    /**
     * @Override from IMessage
     */
    public void setIput(I input) {

    }

    /**
     * @Override from IMessage
     */
    public O getResult() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The goal for this message is to have a Message that implements iMessage and the Input class must be an implementation of IBasicInput and the output an implementation of IBasicOutput

When instantiating this class

```
IMessage<IBasicInput,IBasicOutput> message = new Type1Message<BasicInput1,BasicOutput1>();
```

I got this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from
>   Type1Message to
>   IMessage

I cant understand why. Type1Message implements IMessage and BasicInput and BasicOutput both implements the signature interfaces.

However,using the class instead the interface  works fine
    IMessage message = new Type1Message();

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Generics types are not inherited.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) To make it compiles:

```
IMessage<? extends IBasicInput, ? extends IBasicOutput> message =
    new Type1Message<BasicInput1, BasicOutput1>();
```

That has its [restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html), so I'd write like:

```
IMessage<IBasicInput, IBasicOutput> message = new Type1Message<>();
```